# Почему Data-in возвращает null?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, помогите исправить ошибку. Вывожу слайд так

```
<p data-position="10,50" data-step="0" data-out="left" data-in="right" class="slider_1"><? echo $m->text ?></a></p>
```

Обращаюсь так

```
var maxDataIn = $('.active-slide').data('in');
```

Но при выводе в консоль

```
console.log(maxDataIn);
```

мне пишет `null`.

Comment: У вас класс слайда `slider_1`, а не `active-slide`.

Comment: хинт: в консоли можно сразу писать `$('.active-slide')` и тогда сразу будет видно что селектор вам возвращает пустой набор. Т.е. селектор у вас попросту неправильный.

Comment: Но у меня он не дает null, а выводит информацию про слайд. Хотя спасибо, не знал про такую возможность!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере селектор `$('.slider_1')` - проверьте, что `.active-slide` назначен

Comment: Смотрите, я делаю так $('.slider .active-slide').data('in','none'); 
Но анимация у блока не пропадает. То есть свойство data-in не меняется.

Comment: одно из другого не следует, как у вас устроена анимация из задачи не явно. Для начала распечатайте `.data('in')`, если действительно не меняется - распечатайте   `$('.slider .active-slide')`